# How can I display the values of the accelerometer?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I tried to display the values of the accelerometer on my app but it doesn't work.

```
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            return;
        float mSensorX, mSensorY;
        switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    mSensorX = -sensorEvent.values[0];
                    mSensorY = -sensorEvent.values[1];
                    break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                mSensorX = sensorEvent.values[1];
                mSensorY = -sensorEvent.values[0];
                break;
        }
        sensorTextView.text = String.format("x={0;f}; y={1:f}, z={2:f}", sensorEvent.values[0], sensorEvent.values[1], sensorEvent.values[2]);
    }
```

I'm not sure of the sensorTextView.text part, I saw this on another forum.

Comment: considering the code you've shown, I somewhat understand why nothing is shown.

Comment: yeah..but still?  @Stultuske

Comment: What does `sensorTextView` prints when you run the app? a bunch o zeros?

Comment: nothing, it can't even run the app, because i dont know what to put next after sensorTextView.*

Comment: "it can't even run the app",  so that's the main issue. why not?

Comment: it says : "error:cannot find symbol variable text" because sensorTextView.text doesn't work

Comment: no, that means that that variable doesn't exist, and that your code can't compile

Comment: was the code you found in Kotlin? sensorTextView.text could simply be sensorTextView.setText("your text in here")